# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\isan\hasildata.php on line 21

Tags: php, arrays, json, maps, distance

Hi I receive the following error in my homework and I do not know what is the problem hasildata.php on line 21 :

```
$dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$from."&destinations=".$to."&key=%20AIzaSyCWpwVwu1hO6TJW1H8x_zlhrLfbSbQ2r3o");

$data = json_decode($dataJson,true);
$nilaiJarak = $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
$time=$data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnu7p.png)

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($dataJson)` and include the content to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You must check whether your request is OK or not

```
$dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$from."&destinations=".$to."&key=%20AIzaSyCWpwVwu1hO6TJW1H8x_zlhrLfbSbQ2r3o");
$data = json_decode($dataJson,true);
if ($data['status'] !== "OK") {
    // Error
    echo $data['error_message'];

    // Do something
} else {
    $nilaiJarak = $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $time=$data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
}
```

Comment: when I changed the key to the Google program it went smoothly without errors, thank you for the solution